# Impossible (so far) to get any asp.net mvc error info on UAT IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, logging

We have a web app that is running fine on dev machines and dev servers. For some very unknown reason (that's the whole point), the app does not run on our OAT server. Our situation is:

- CustomErrors=Off not working
- No log files
- No Event Viewer entries

By design, the application is not logging anything (sad, I know). It does have a custom error redirect, which is working, but pointing to a page and controller that does not exists, it was never implemented.

So my first try was to set up CustomErrors and check on browser itself what is wrong. No luck. I have tried to change web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Again, no luck. Our L2 support does not have access to modify machine.config and set , so customerror is not an option.

Next, I have tried trace and log4net files (worked on dev machine and servers):

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="dasAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="dasAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\DAS\Das.webApp.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Used %ALLUSERSPROFILE%, %temp%, IIS log folder. None have worked.

I don't know what to do next. Does anyone have any Idea?

Thank you

Comment: so you are seeing 404 not found error for every request. Is it?

Comment: Also did you check the windows logs?? you can see them by typing `eventvwr`  after start+R

Comment: Hi @It'satrap, exacly. We get an error, IIS tries to redirect to a custom error page that doesn't exists. Bum: 404.

Comment: And no entry on Event Viewer.

Comment: You have to check application logs in that. It's not possible that there is no entry in windows logs. Windows logs each and every thing. Sometimes the error can be located in a warning or information item. Make sure to check them also. Just note the time at which you fire the app and look for all entries at that time

Comment: All we got on eventvwe is an entry like this:
Event code: 4010 
Event message: An unhandled security exception has occurred. 
Event time: 06/04/2017 13:34:19 
Event time (UTC): 06/04/2017 12:34:19 
Event ID: 89ab2f688c2e409e8274320397da95d0 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Comment: Digging further on this error and I found that it is usually related to a permission issue... Trying some solutions, Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815653/event-message-an-unhandled-access-exception-has-occurred-iis-7-5-cannot-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it, but the team did.

They have added the following on web.config

```
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

and

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```