# An unhandled access exception has occurred when running web site in IIS Express, VS 2017

Tags: c#, iis, c#-4.0

When running Website in IIS Express, browser returns with 500 server error. As per the event log, it says "An unhandled access exception has occurred."

```
Event log details:

Event code: 4011 
Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred. 
Event time: 1/05/2019 7:38:17 PM 
Event time (UTC): 1/05/2019 7:38:17 AM 
Event ID: 1dcf9c41edb04864b0baf2b384982bcd 
Event sequence: 5 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-XXXXX 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ecommerce\Source\Website\ 
    Machine name: XXXX-LAPTOP 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 22520 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: XXXX-LAPTOP\xxxx 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:31499/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: XXXX-LAPTOP\xxxx 

Custom event details:
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: you should be able to debug this and find out what specifically caused the exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred (IIS 7.5, cannot load website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815653/event-message-an-unhandled-access-exception-has-occurred-iis-7-5-cannot-load)

Answer (score 0):

This was happen due to a config change in the web.config file. Actually, some one has added Azure Event config, when remove it site working properly.

Thank you.